# Get current page number in ListView

Tags: django, django-views

How does one get the Paginator info in a class based view? I want to call a function from within get_context_data and I need to pass the current page and the last page.

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from .utils import pageList

class PeopleView(ListView):
    model = People
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'people'

    def get_context_date(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(People, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['page-list'] = pageList(<current_page>, <last_page>)
        return context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snipped is from django source code `views/generic/list.py`:

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    """Get the context for this view."""
    queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
    page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
    context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
    if page_size:
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
        context = {
            'paginator': paginator,  #<--- (1)
            'page_obj': page,        #<--- (2)
            'is_paginated': is_paginated,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    else:
        context = {
             ....
        }
    if context_object_name is not None:
        context[context_object_name] = queryset
    context.update(kwargs)
    return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

It means that in your `context` the [page_obj](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#page-objects) and the [paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view) are availables. You can write expressions as:

```
{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}  (2)
```

or

```
{{ paginator.num_pages }}    (1)
```

Also you can write:

```
def get_context_date(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    my_function(  )  
    context['page-list'] = pageList(context['page_obj'].number, 
                                    context['paginator'].num_pages)
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks! Worst part is I knew those were available, I'm using them in my template...